# UK COVID: any consequences if a passenger locator form was not completed for a brief entry?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, paperwork, covid-19

I had a layover in the UK recently on a trip from the U.S. to the EU, where I had to exit the international transfer zone to check in for the next flight. I did not complete a passenger locator form.

In principle, a "passenger locator form" is required for all entries to the UK due to COVID. However, my entry was for about one hour, and I did not leave the airport.

I am wondering, did I really violate anything, and could there be any consequences the next time I enter the UK?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If nothing happened then and there, you're all good. However, you did indeed break the law, and had you been asked for it (you usually aren't), you would've faced a £100 fine.

In fact it's even required if **not** leaving the transit area. While check-in/gate staff mostly haven't been checking it, for my very most recent flight (from CPH), CFS staff weren't letting anyone without a completed form on the flight.